# Cast &Vec<char> as &str

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec<Vec<char>>` as a console frame buffer.

I'd like to render the buffer, but it would make me to `print!()` every char. I would like to represent the inner `&Vec<char>` as `&str` (not converting, not making a new String, but just casting) to print it as a whole with `print!()`.

Is it possible, or is `print!()` already as fast for many characters as `print!()` for a single string slice?

Comment: You cannot cast a [char](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html) to a `&str`. The latter is effectively a variable sized sequence of `u8`s.

Comment: My question is why you have a `Vec<char>` in the first place. It's usually better to use a `String` instead.

Comment: @Aloso it's sort of a game screen, so I have to update individual chars regularly

Comment: If you can confine your character set strictly to ASCII, you can store `u8`s instead of `char`s. Every ASCII-encoded `u8` has the same representation in UTF-8. A `&[u8]` would then be a valid `&str`, and you can convert using [from_utf8](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) or [from_utf8_unchecked](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8_unchecked.html). This will re-interpret the data [in place](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fbfa91ab439674ec84ffd0100c80f955).

Comment: @IInspectable yeah thanks! I was thinking about this, though it's sad to limit only to ASCII. If only we had a standard UTF16 String option...

Comment: Correct UTF-16 would have exactly the same problems, as it’s also variable length, so a `Vec<char>` wouldn’t be compatible with a `&[u16]` either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `&str` represents a reference to a memory location where a string is stored encoded using UTF-8.

Since your `Vec<char>` is not a string encoded using UTF-8, there is no way around creating a new `String` in memory somewhere that you can then reference.

Luckily it's easy and fast to convert, if `v` is your `Vec<char>`, it's simply `v.iter().cloned().collect::<String>()`. If you no longer wish to keep the old `v` around, you can replace `.iter().cloned()` with `.into_iter()`.

Comment: The conversion is indeed fast, though constructing a `String` generally involves a heap allocation. Heap allocations are among the most expensive operations we commonly perform.

Comment: @IInspectable In theory the conversion should be possible to do inside the memory buffer of the `Vec<char>` plus a small bit constant on the stack, passing that to `String`.